# Is it possible to make an asynchronous call in JXA Objective-C bridge

Tags: objective-c, scripting-bridge, javascript-automation

I'm trying to use Objective-C Bridge in a Javascript for Automation script to access the Event Store. Here's my code:

```
ObjC.import('EventKit');

var store = $.EKEventStore.alloc.initWithAccessToEntityTypes($.EKEntityMaskReminder);
var predicate = store.predicateForRemindersInCalendars($.Nil);

store.fetchRemindersMatchingPredicateCompletion(predicate, function(reminders){
console.log(reminders)
});
```

However the script completes, presumably before the function is called- nothing appears in the log.

Is there a way to make this work, such as to make it run synchronously instead, or to make the script wait until the completion handler finishes?

Comment: JXA _can_ work with asynchronous Cocoa APIs, but it requires your script be a stay open script application. I’m not sure it that will work for your example: I’ve only dabbled in this using the `NSMetadataQuery` API, which is notification based, and that turned out to a) work and b) be a royal pain, as I would have needed to devise an IPC comm channel to get results back to the caller; YMMV, depending on how self contained your script is. Again without knowledge as to your example, you might find a synchronous equivalent to your API call easier, like `CFQuery` turned out to be in my case.